# Reliable Service Data Model Issue

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm new to Azure Service Fabric, and watched Ivan Gavryliuk's "Understanding the Programming Models of Azure Service Fabric" course on Pluralsight. I've been following along and the basic data model in the reliable service and API work as explained in the course.

However, if I increase the complexity of the data model used I hit an error.

Product.cs from the ECommerce.ProductCatelog.Model

```
namespace ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model
{
   public class Product
   {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }

      public string Description { get; set; }

      public double Price { get; set; }

      public int Availability { get; set; }
      public Supplier Suppliers { get; set; }
   }

   public class Supplier
   {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }

   }
}
```

ApiProduct.cs from ECommerce.API.Model

```
   public class ApiProduct
   {
      [JsonProperty("id")]
      public Guid Id { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("name")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("description")]
      public string Description { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("price")]
      public double Price { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("isAvailable")]
      public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("suppliers")]
      public ApiSupplier suppliers { get; set; }

   }

   public class ApiSupplier
   {
      [JsonProperty("id")]
      public Guid Id { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty("name")]
      public string Name { get; set; }

   }
```

ProductController.cs from Ecommerce.API.Controlers

```
[HttpGet]
      public async Task<IEnumerable<ApiProduct>> GetAsync()
      {
         IEnumerable<Product> allProducts = await _service.GetAllProductsAsync();

         return allProducts.Select(p => new ApiProduct
         {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            Description = p.Description,
            Price = p.Price,
            IsAvailable = p.Availability > 0,
            suppliers = p.Suppliers
         });
      }
```

The last line in the above block triggers an intellisense error:
*"Cannot implicitly convert type 'ECommerce.ProductCatelog.Model.Supplier' to 'ECommerce.API.Model.Supplier'*"

Any suggestions on how to work around this welcome :)

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: Link to the GitHub repo where the course code is hosted - https://github.com/fgheysels/ServiceFabric.ECommerce/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not specific to Service Fabric but C# in general. You are trying to set a variable with a value of a different type.

In this line:

```
IEnumerable<Product> allProducts = await _service.GetAllProductsAsync();
```

You get a collection of items of type `ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model.Product`. In this class, you added the property `Suppliers` (which should be `Supplier` since it's not a collection) of type `ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model.Supplier`.

Now, with the following line:

```
     return allProducts.Select(p => new ApiProduct
     {
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        Description = p.Description,
        Price = p.Price,
        IsAvailable = p.Availability > 0,
        suppliers = p.Suppliers
     });
```

you are converting this collection to a collection of a new type `ECommerce.API.Model.Product`, to which you added a new property `Suppliers` of type `ECommerce.API.Model.Supplier`, but you set this property to the original value, without converting it. So, convert the original `Suppliers` property to the correct type:

```
     return allProducts.Select(p => new ApiProduct
     {
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        Description = p.Description,
        Price = p.Price,
        IsAvailable = p.Availability > 0,
        suppliers = new ApiSupplier
        {
           Id = p.Suppliers.Id,
           Name = p.Suppliers.Name
        }    
     });
```

---

**Update: make Suppliers a collection**

Make your Suppliers property a collection both in your data model and in your Api model:

```
 public Collection<ApiSupplier> suppliers { get; set; }
```

Then convert the collection accordingly:

```
     return allProducts.Select(p => new ApiProduct
     {
        Id = p.Id,
        Name = p.Name,
        Description = p.Description,
        Price = p.Price,
        IsAvailable = p.Availability > 0,
        suppliers = p.Suppliers.Select(s => new ApiSupplier
           {
             Id = s.Id,
             Name = s.Name
           }    
     });
```

Comment: Hi @Francesc, Yeah I'm quite new to C# too. Thanks for your insight. Your explanation makes sense, however I see the same kind of error with your solution: Cannot implicitly convert type: ECommerce.ProductCatalog.Model.Supplier to ECommerce.API.Mode.Supplier.

Comment: I used the wrong type name. Check the updated answer. It should be ApiSupplier

Comment: Yep, that nailed it. I need to read up on the data model side more. This example appears to map a single supplier to the product. To map multiple suppliers is it just a case of defining the Product model as something like: Collection<Supplier> supplier { get; set; } ? And how would you reflect that in the controller? BTW feel free to point me at docs/articles instead. Appreciate the insight.

Comment: I've added a sample on how to make Suppliers a collection. Regarding docs and articles, I don't have links but I would start with any general C# tutorial and LINQ.

Comment: as an FYI the solution for collection of suppliers didn't work. I had to define the supplier as: public Collection<Supplier>  Suppliers { get; set; }. And the same error persists: Cannot implicitly convert type.
So I'm still investigating the solution.

Comment: Check that you are using the right types. The Collection in your ProductCatalog.Model should use the Supplier and in the Api.Model, should use the ApiSupplier.

Comment: I did. The work around I found in the end was to append .ToList(); for the Suppliers LINQ syntax and use List instead of Collections in the model. I'm currently looking at AutoMapper to make this a lot less verbose.

Comment: Ah, of course, I missed that! the Select returns an IEnumerable, not a Collection, so you definitely need the ToList. Regarding AutoMapper, I would not do it, but that's your choice obviously. I prefer typing a few lines of code to map a type to another rather than deal with all sorts of mysterious bugs in random places due to the auto-magic not working for x reason. But I know that many people like it.

Comment: Sage advise. Perhaps I'll push on then. I hit a handful of new issues :) so either way I'm learning new "things" as I work through the typical CRUD activities only now in a SF context. Appreciate your help on this issue!